# Reinstall WordPress Without Losing Data

Tags: customization

So I recently had issues with my WordPress database.

goDaddy created an updated MySQL and then files got thrown all over, things missing, etc.  It got to the point where they pretty much told me that they had no clue what they did and they couldn't fix it. :(

What I want to do is start over without losing my posts, comments, photos, etc.

I've searched online and all of the answers are ones that I do not understand.  I use goDaddy hosting and have downloaded the new WordPress file, as well as my theme file.

How do I make sure that all of my prior posts, pictures, comments etc., get transferred over once I upload these files to my host?

Comment: Is your site working at all? If you can post a screenshot or something on what's going wrong/what you're now seeing that would help. Are you gettings errors, blank screen, etc? First step is to figure out what's going wrong, before you jump the gun on a fresh install if you don't have to. It could just be your media folder got moved or something which would be like a 2 second fix.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **Tools -> [Export](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen)** to save your posts and pages. Then you could reinstall your WordPress, upload your theme and Import your content back.

This can fix corrupted WordPress core or theme files but you would have to setup your theme options and settings again.

Answer (score 1):

**Back up the Old Directors and file .**

1. your copies of everything except the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/ directory with fresh copies from the **Public_html.**

***- Reinstalling WordPress after a Hack / damage / mis-configured.***

1. First you'll want to download the [latest version of WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/download) to your local computer.
2. Extract the files in the **.zip** archive you downloaded to a local folder.

   3.Using **FTP**, upload all of the folders and files contained within the wordpress directory to your **public_html** directory. Or if your    domain was an **addon domain** and its document root was in a    sub-directory make sure you're uploading it there. You can do this by    hitting **Ctrl-A** in your **FTP** client when you're in the    left-hand pane to select all the files, then simply drag them onto    the server.
3. Once the files are done uploading, navigate to the quarantine directory on the server side, right-click on **wp-config.php** and    choose **View/Edit.** Your FTP application should prompt you for what    application you'd like to open the file with, you can just use a text    editor such as Notepad. Then finally copy down the database    information from the define**('DB_...)** sections.

   5.At this point if you try to simply access the site you'll get a WordPress error about no **wp-config.php** file.

   6.Back in your FTP client, navigate to your **public_html** directory and you should see a file called **wp-config-sample.php**,    right-click on this file and choose View/Edit, open the file in    Notepad then fill in your **database name, database user, and    database user password.**
      Then hit **Ctrl-S** to save the file, in a few seconds your FTP    client should prompt you if you'd like to save this back to the    server, click Yes. You can also place a check beside Finish editing    and delete local file if your FTP client gives you that option.
4. Now in your FTP client right-click on **wp-config-sample.php** choose Rename, and then name the file just **wp-config.php**.

   8.Now in this case if we try to go to our site again it's an all blank page, the reason for this is because our site used a custom    theme, and those theme files are still quarantined. So next in your    FTP client navigate to the **/quarantine/wp-content/themes**    directory, and drag over the pinboard directory (or whichever theme    you used) to your local computer.

   9.Now navigate on the server side to the **/public_html/wp-content/themes** directory, and then drag the **pin-board** directory from the local computer to the server.

   10.You should now be able to hopefully pull up your website again free of any malicious hacks.